# На конце дробного числа из неоткуда взялись цифры

Tags: javascript, числа

Беру число из input, отбрасываю у него дробную часть и сохраняю результат в переменную, затем отнимаю от изначального числа то, что получилось, таким образом получаю дробную часть(результат), но на конце у результата какие то непонятные цифры https://prnt.sc/12khwko

Comment: `console.log(0.1 + 0.2); /* 0.3000...004 */ console.log( (0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(2) ); // "0.30"` (обращаю внимание, toFixed дает строку. Если затем нужно работать с этим как с числом, нужно дополнительно превратить полученную строку в число. `Number("0.30")` или `+"0.30"`)

Comment: А что если я хочу работать с дробью любой длинны ?

Comment: Так или иначе периодически в дробях будут возникать такие "хвосты". Неточность слишком маленькая, и в подавляющем большинстве случаев не мешает работе программы. Только нужно быть осторожным со сравнениями. Если это цикл, вместо `x === 0.3` по возможности использовать `>=` и `<=`, а для сравнения можно сделать функию типа `function equal(a, b) { return Math.abs(a - b) < 0.000000001; }` → `console.log( 0.1 + 0.2 === 0.3 ); // false` но `console.log( equal(0.1 + 0.2, 0.3) ); // true`

Comment: По сути, исправлять неточность нужно только для вывода на экран. Можно сделать короткую функцию `function dec(n, prec) { return Number( n.toFixed(prec || 2) ) }` для вывода дробных. Чтобы везде не париться с toFixed, а просто вызвать `console.log( dec(0.1 + 0.2) ) // 0.3`